# Changing the How to ask section when asking a new question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I hang around EE.SE a lot these days and keep checking on the new question like a challenge to myself if I could figure out how to solve it. But what I encounter is a lot of bad questions. So I just have this simple suggestion to make an edit to how to ask section that displays a little more informative like, Asking the OP if he has researched the topic before asking , Or does he need to provide links/block diagram/documents/schematic for the question he is asking. Or putting up a new page between clicking the "Ask Question" and "Editor to ask question" that gives a detailed description about Do's and Dont's of asking question?

I know people are still gonna skip reading that. But just a suggestion.

Comment: Do you really think those people that ask bad questions have read that section and just not understood it?

Comment: I 'feel' they completely ignore the section because it simply is not catchy to the eye. Plus the guidelines are enough in the section but, they are quite brief.

Comment: But you assume they even open the page instead of right away clickg on "ask question" and type away?

Comment: No. They just click "Ask Question" and start typing. And add the unrelated tag and Submit. Probably.

Comment: They even write their questions in the box named _Your Answer_. "I also bought this, did you get it to work?"

Comment: @pipe I guess there is nothing one can do about it except flag.

Answer (score -2):

A better way is to use the tag system to find questions that are useful to you to ask. There are [advanced search features](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) if you wish to use them.

Changes to the site are changed site wide, so that means all of stack exchange. It is unlikely that you'll get any change made, you can ask questions on the meta meta site, but if your not a dev or have literally the best idea in the world (and I mean that in the strongest sense) then they won't get implemented.

Comment: I see. It's not about irrelevant tag but making asking question a lil more interactive. But it is not the best idea. I don't even have an idea. Thank You